# What's the proper suffix to use for Retina iPad images?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

For a iPad-only application, what is the proper suffix to add to images to be automatically used for a Retina display?

Ex:  If I have an image called "myimage.png", does the Retina image have to be named:"myimage@2x.png"?

I just want to add all the retina image to the Xcode project and get it automatically used/taken if was a Retina iPad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you use the @2x suffix for high resolution assets. That's valid for all devices with Retina displays, including the new iPad.

Comment: Answer to Myself: Fro the simulator, On Hardware, just select iPad(Retina)  Word great!